# Raspberry Pi : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ServerInterface'

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, paramiko

I am creating an application emulating ssh. I am running the application using a Raspberry Pi. When I launch the application, I receive this error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ServerInterface'
```

Here is the code for importing paramiko :

```
#paramiko
import paramiko
```

The code works on my desktop computer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely you named your file as paramiko.py which overrides the Python module paramiko. Rename your file and try again. Or there is some other file in your PYTHONPATH that is named paramiko.py

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> globals()['paramiko']
```

will tell you from where paramiko is loaded. For me:

```
>>> globals()['paramiko']
<module 'paramiko' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: How can I see what files are in the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @bendacoder I edited my answer with the info you requested.

Comment: helloV, I have the same output as you.

Comment: Then check if ServerInterface attribute exists. Are you doing this on RPI?
`
>>> 'ServerInterface' in dir(paramiko)
True
>>> paramiko.ServerInterface
<class 'paramiko.ServerInterface'>
>>> `

Comment: When I used your command, it told me False. Once I reinstalled paramiko without using pip, it all worked. Thank you for your time.